# What is the best way to add flutter dependencies?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec.yaml

We can add flutter dependencies by the following ways. I want to know which one is efficient and also the differences between the following ways

1. `'cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2'   // What's the use if we use version number`
2. `'cupertino_icons: '         // What if we don't mention the version number`
3. `'cupertino_icons: any'      // difference between (2 and 3)`

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#hosted-packages

Comment: @mmcdon20 Thanks for your answer. But I already saw that post , There is no answer for point no.2 and 3

Comment: It says "If no version constraint is given, any is assumed." which means 2 and 3 are the same.

Comment: ``The string any allows any version. This is equivalent to an empty version constraint, but is more explicit. Although any is allowed, we don’t recommend it.``

Answer (score 1):

When you add dependency like `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2` it will get any version between `1.0.2` and `2.0.0` and looks for compatible version with your `flutter` and `dart` version and other packages,

when you add dependency like `cupertino_icons: any` it will get any version that compatible with your `flutter` and `dart` version and other packages.

also there is another version that is `cupertino_icons: 1.0.2` which get exact `1.0.2` version of `cupertino_icons`.

Comment: what about point no.2

Comment: I explain number 3, I don't know about number 2. @AnandhKrishnan